# How to throw an alert error when registering an existing email in the database with Angular?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, validation, server-side-validation

So my question is about when I want to register a new employee with his email on my database, i want Angular to check if the email or the Id of the employee already exist and then if you submit an existing email or id to show an error that it would tell you that the "Email Already Exists" either the "EmployeeId Already Exists". I will post below my codes of my api controller, the js file, the class file of my BusinessLogicLayer and the html file to tell me where i am wrong.

**EmployeeController.cs**

```
namespace EIS.API.Controllers
{
[EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
public class EmployeeController : ApiController
{
    EmployeeBs employeeObjBs;

    public EmployeeController()
    {
        employeeObjBs = new EmployeeBs();
    }

    //GET /api/employeee

    [ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Employee>))]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(employeeObjBs.GetALL());
    }

    //GET /api/employeee/1

    [ResponseType(typeof(Employee))]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(string id)
    {
        Employee employee = employeeObjBs.GetByID(id);
        if (employee != null)
            return Ok(employee);
        else
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
    }

    //POST /api/employeee

    [ResponseType(typeof(Employee))]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(Employee employee)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (employeeObjBs.Insert(employee))
            {
                return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = employee.EmployeeId }, employee);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var error in employeeObjBs.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
                }
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
    }

    //UPDATE /api/employeee

    [ResponseType(typeof(Employee))]
    public IHttpActionResult Put(string id, Employee employee)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            employeeObjBs.Update(employee);
            return Ok(employee);
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
    }

    //DELETE /api/employeee

    public IHttpActionResult Delete(string id)
    {
        Employee employee = employeeObjBs.GetByID(id);
        if (employee != null)
        {
            employeeObjBs.Delete(id);
            return Ok(employee);
        }
        else
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
    }
}
}
```

**EmployeeBs.cs**

```
namespace EIS.BLL
{
public class EmployeeBs
{
    private EmployeeDb ObjDb;

    public List<string> Errors = new List<string>();

    public EmployeeBs()
    {
        ObjDb = new EmployeeDb();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Employee> GetALL()
    {
        return ObjDb.GetALL().ToList();
    }

    public Employee GetByID(string Id)
    {
        return ObjDb.GetByID(Id);
    }

    public bool Insert(Employee emp)
    {
        if (IsValidOnInsert(emp))
        {
            ObjDb.Insert(emp);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void Delete(string Id)
    {
        ObjDb.Delete(Id);

    }

    public bool Update(Employee emp)
    {
        if (IsValidOnUpdate(emp))
        {
            ObjDb.Update(emp);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Employee GetByEmail(string email)
    {
        return ObjDb.GetByEmail(email);
    }

    public Employee RecoverPasswordByEmail(string email)
    {
        var emp = ObjDb.GetByEmail(email);
        return emp;
    }

    public bool IsValidOnInsert(Employee emp)
    {
        //Unique Employee Id Validation
        string EmployeeIdValue = emp.EmployeeId;
        int count = GetALL().Where(x => x.EmployeeId == EmployeeIdValue).ToList().Count();
        if (count != 0)
        {
            Errors.Add("Employee Id Already Exist");
        }

        //Unique Email Validation
        string EmailValue = emp.Email;
        count = GetALL().Where(x => x.Email == EmailValue).ToList().Count();
        if (count != 0)
        {
            Errors.Add("Email Already Exist");
        }

        //Your own Business Rules Validations

        if (Errors.Count() == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public bool IsValidOnUpdate(Employee emp)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

**EmployeeMgmt.html**

```
<div id="alert" class="alert alert-success" ng-show="Flg">
{{message}}
```

```
<form name="createEmployeeForm" novalidate>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Create Employee Profile</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2">Employee Id *</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="Emp.EmployeeId" name="EmployeeId" value="EmployeeId" required/>
                </div>


            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2">Email *</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="Emp.Email" name="Email" value="Email" required/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-6">
                    <button type="submit" value="Create" ng-click="CreateEmployee(Emp,createEmployeeForm.$valid )" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Create</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li class="alert alert-danger" ng-if="createEmployeeForm.$submitted && createEmployeeForm.EmployeeId.$invalid">EmployeeId is required</li>
                <li class="alert alert-danger" ng-if="createEmployeeForm.$submitted && createEmployeeForm.Email.$error.required">Email is required</li>
                <li class="alert alert-danger" ng-if="createEmployeeForm.$submitted && createEmployeeForm.Email.$error.email">Email is Invalid</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
                <li class="alert alert-danger" ng-repeat="item in serverErrorMsgs">{{item[0]}}</li>
            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</form>
<div class="well">
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="search" placeholder="Type in to search employee" />
</div>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Profiles List - {{msg}}</h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td ng-click="Sort('EmployeeId')"><a><u>EmployeeId</u></a></td>
                <td ng-click="Sort('Email')"><a><u>Email</u></a></td>
                <td ng-click="Sort('FirstName')"><a><u>Name</u></a></td>
                <td ng-click="Sort('Contact')"><a><u>Contact</u></a></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr dir-paginate="emp in Emps | filter: search | orderBy: key: AscOrDesc |itemsPerPage:10 ">
                <td>{{emp.EmployeeId}}</td>
                <td>{{emp.Email}}</td>
                <td>{{emp.FirstName}} {{emp.LastName}}</td>
                <td>{{emp.Contact}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <dir-pagination-controls max-size="3"
                             direction-links="true"
                             boundary-links="true">

    </dir-pagination-controls>
</div>
</div>
```

**employeeMgmt.js**

```
appEIS.factory("employeeMgmtService",
function ($http) {
    var empMgmtObj = {};

    empMgmtObj.getAll = function () {
        var Emps = $http({ method: "Get", url: "http://localhost:53431/api/employee" }); (function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });

        return Emps;
    };

    empMgmtObj.CreateEmployee = function (emp) {
        var Emp = $http({ method: "Post", url: "http://localhost:53431/api/employee", data: emp }); (function (response) {
            return response.data;
        }, function (error) {
            return error.data;
        });

        return Emp;
    };

    return empMgmtObj;
});

appEIS.controller("employeeMgmtController", function ($scope, employeeMgmtService, utilityService) {
$scope.msg = "Manage Employee Profiles.";

employeeMgmtService.getAll().then(function (result) {
    $scope.Emps = result.data;
});

$scope.Sort = function (col) {
    $scope.key = col;
    $scope.AscOrDesc = !$scope.AscOrDesc;
};

$scope.CreateEmployee = function(Emp, IsValid) {
    if (IsValid) {
        Emp.Password = utilityService.randomPassword();
        employeeMgmtService.CreateEmployee(Emp).then(function(result) {
            if (result.ModelState == null) {
                $scope.message = "You have successfully created an Employee with Id: " + result.data.EmployeeId;
                $scope.Flg = true;
                employeeMgmtService.getAll().then(function(result) {
                    $scope.Emps = result.data;
                });

                utilityService.myAlert();
            } else {
                $scope.serverErrorMsgs = result.ModelState;
            }
        });
    }
};
});
```

**Employee.cs**

```
namespace EIS.BOL
{
[Table("Employee")]
 public partial class Employee
{
    public Employee()
    {
        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        RoleId = 2;
    }   

    [Key]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }


    [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Contact { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DOJ { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    public double? TotalExp { get; set; }
    public double? RelevantExp { get; set; }
    public string BankName { get; set; }
    public string IFSCCode { get; set; }
    public string AcNo { get; set; }
    public string Pan { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
}
```

**EmployeeDb.cs**

```
namespace EIS.DAL
{
public class EmployeeDb:DALBase
{
    public IEnumerable<Employee> GetALL()
    {
        return db.Employees.ToList();
    }
    public Employee GetByID(string Id)
    {
        return db.Employees.Find(Id);
    }
    public void Insert(Employee emp)
    {
        db.Employees.Add(emp);
        Save();
    }
    public void Delete(string Id)
    {
        Employee emp = db.Employees.Find(Id);
        db.Employees.Remove(emp);
        Save();
    }
    public void Update(Employee emp)
    {
        db.Entry(emp).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
        Save();
        db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = true;
    }
    public Employee GetByEmail(string email)
    {
        return db.Employees.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == email);
    }
    public void Save()
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
}
```

So i want to display the error in the serverErrorMsgs which is from the Modelstate that you see in my controller on the POST method. I have made a list for the error in the class file but when i am submiting it is just doing nothing nor displaying the error.

Answer (score 0):

Database management system will handle the duplicated column error.

> UNIQUE Constraints. If a UNIQUE constraint is added to a column that has duplicated values, the Database Engine returns an error and does not add the constraint. The Database Engine automatically creates a UNIQUE index to enforce the uniqueness requirement of the UNIQUE constraint.

You can register a listener to handle the “unique error “ from database engine and output the custom information.

1. update the specified database column to add unique constraints.
2. Insert a duplicated value into the table and record the error information.
3. According to the error information, to capture it by coding try-catch clause. Do what you want in “catch” phrase.

Your exception have 3 chances to occur:

1. The value inserted into db even if it was a duplicated value.
2. The error did occurred but it wasn’t captured correctly.
3. The error was captured successfully but the data weren’t sent to the html pages.

hope for helping.

Comment: How I do that in my code so? Sorry I am new to Angular and I am stuck here on this about 7 days

Comment: @ΜιχαηλΤσιγαρας wait a minute i will update my answer

Comment: maybe the approach i told was misunderstanded. if you see on my html file ng-repeat is not working. The error works fine and i dont get a duplicate Email or Id my problem is that I want to display the error on the page when inserting an existing value, so in other words ng-repat not displaying the error on the html file. I think the error is on the js file and it has to be something withe $scope.serverErrorMsgs or the result.Modelstate

Comment: @ΜιχαηλΤσιγαρας sorry i will see

Comment: @ΜιχαηλΤσιγαρας have you debugged? Insert some break points in the isInsertValid method and watch what is going to happen.

Comment: I wiil try and tell you

Comment: So how i pass the error in an alert message when submiting the existing email tp show on the html?

Comment: @ΜιχαηλΤσιγαρας before passing you need to confirm that the error were found in the employeebs.cd

Comment: that is not helping either :( my problem is that i want to display the error when the user registers with AngularJs.

Comment: <ul>
                <li class="alert alert-danger" ng-repeat="item in serverErrorMsgs">{{item[0]}}</li>
            </ul>  


in that line it must diplay the error

Comment: ΜιχαηλΤσιγαρας my computer will be delivered tomorrow, So I can’t debug it right now. You should try controlling the variable of your program in a small scope, which will be easier to solve the problem.